# Selection of cell in SWT Tree (multiple columns)

Tags: java, eclipse, tree, swt, treetable

I'm currently trying to change an existing SWT-application and have to modify a Tree with multiple columns (Treetable) to provide selection of single "cells" in all of these columns. By default i can only select elements in the first column or the entire row when setting SWT.FULL_SELECTION. I'm new to SWT and hours of searching didn't pay off. Is there a way to realize this?

Comment: By "select", do you just mean "highlight"?

Comment: @Baz: I mean the highlighting (blue inking) of the clicked cell and the "internal selection". Calling tree.getSelection() should return the highlighted TreeItem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the usage of `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewerFocusCellManager` to customize the selection of `Tree/Table` Item cells.

Comment: I've already found a working JFace solution in a snippet, but sadly i have to do it without.

Comment: I am afraid  you will endup doing the same thing what org.eclipse.jface.viewers.SWTFocusCellManager is already doing. Not sure why you shouldnt use existing viewer functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SWT.SINGLE? 
after setting that..probably you will have to add something like:

```
treeTable.addSelectionListener( new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected( SelectionEvent e )
            {
                Object selectedObj = e.item;
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected( SelectionEvent e )
            {
            }

        });
```

Comment: SWT.SINGLE does only effect the amount of selections (single or multiselection), unfortunately it does not enable the tree to provide selections in additional columns. The code you posted won't change this, i guess.

Answer (score 0):

SWT Tree and Table controls do not support cell-level selection as this isn't supported by native controls that these widgets are based on. There are custom draw overlay solutions in JFace that others have already referenced, but they don't work all that well, especially when it comes to matching the native appearance of the selection. Alternatively, you may find that widgets available in the Nebula project (http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/) are a better fit for your requirements.